# Does there exists any $x$ such that $x\geq AM\geq GM?$ If not,how do I prove it is unbounded?

Tags: surfaces, geometric-inequalities

We know $AM\geq GM$.Or,in words,$AM$ has a minimum value when it is equal to $GM$?But,by any chance is there any way to find $x$ such that it is the upper limit of $AM$?

My inspiration for this question-

> My friend gave me this question-
>
> The volume of a cuboid=$64 m^3$.What is its maximum possible Total Surface Area?

My attempt-

By applying AM-GM I get,

$$\frac{lb+bh+lh}{3}\geq lb\cdot bh\cdot lh^{\frac13}$$

$$\implies2(lb+bh+lh)\geq 96$$

Thus,I get the lower limit of surface area=$96$.But,how do I find the upper limit of surface area?(or in other words how do I find the upper limit of the AM-GM inequality.)

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: It's unbounded.

Comment: @A.S. Can you give any proof using (or not using) limits?

Answer (score 0):

In every such problem, I would like to suggest a good approach which does have a rigorous proof. The minimum and maximum of functions occur at either the boundaries or the symmetry point. In your case, at the symmetry point, the minimum occurs. Hence, the maximum is infinity.

How infinity? Consider a cuboid of infinite length and infinitesimal breadth and height.

Comment: Hey but its cuboid of a specific volume hiw infinity is maxima i really didnt understand what you are saying

Comment: @ArchisWelankar It is a specific volume right, but you see that breadth and height are nearly zero. Then the length has to be reallllly large. If the length is sooo large, total surface area is large as well...I hope I am clear.

Comment: But the length is sooo large,  thus the volume would be large as well. Not to say that the example is wrong, but a sequence of such cuboids, $l= 64n^2$, $w=h=\frac{1}{n}$ might be better.

Comment: Can you write the same thing more mathematically using limit notation?